# White space is showing when clicking link title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Need help. for now im trying to learn foundation framework and using the off-canvass plugin.
my problem is when click the `Title goes here` the div get separated with sidebar. I have manage to take a screenshot of it.

[image]

once you click the `title goes here` there is a white appearing.

you can base on this fiddle.

***[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khQeH/)***

also i tried making the sidebars heigth set to 100% but it is not working

```
 #sidebar {
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -2px 0px 8px -1px #111111;
  box-shadow: inset -2px 0px 8px -1px #111111;
  padding-top: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite figure it out, but It has something to do with `.active [role="main"] { margin-right: -80%; }`